# NameError in Controller and View is only displaying html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, hash, syntax, controller

I spent a few hours yesterday trying to figure this out and it is still frustrating me after taking a break, so I figured that I would ask. Also, sorry if this post is long and my use of terminology is amateurish. I am still really new to programming.

I am trying to make a rails app using the 'themoviedb' gem that will allow users to search themoviedatabase's api. Here is an example project provided by the creator of the gem, which uses an older version of rails: https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb-example. I am trying to recreate this sample app before I start making my own changes, but I am running into trouble with the MoviesController.

Here is the example MoviesController:

```
 class MoviesController < ApplicationController
      def show
        @movie = Tmdb::Movie.detail(params[:id])
        @images = Tmdb::Movie.images(params[:id])
        @cast = Tmdb::Movie.casts(params[:id])
        @trailers = Tmdb::Movie.trailers(params[:id])
        @similar_movies = Tmdb::Movie.similar_movies(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

And here is part of the example Movies#Show View:

```
<h3>Poster</h3>
 <%= image_tag("#{@configuration.base_url}w154#{@movie.poster_path}") if @movie.poster_path %>
<h3>Facts</h3>
  Budget: $<%= number_with_delimiter(@movie.budget, :delimiter => ',') %><br />
  Revenue: $<%= number_with_delimiter(@movie.revenue, :delimiter => ',') %><br />
  Status: <%= @movie.status %><br />
  Runtime: <%= @movie.runtime %><br />
```

If I try to run my application with this example code, then I am given this error:

```
NoMethodError in Movies#show
undefined method `poster_path' for #<Hash:0x007fb615913de0>
app/views/movies/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_movies_show_html_erb___4006517199107153671_70210007215400'
```

My solution was to add a helper method to the MoviesController and refactor the code of the Movies#Show View to fix the hash element error:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :movie

  def show
    @movie = Tmdb::Movie.detail(params[:id])
    @images = Tmdb::Movie.images(params[:id])
    @cast = Tmdb::Movie.casts(params[:id])
    @trailers = Tmdb::Movie.trailers(params[:id])
    @similar_movies = Tmdb::Movie.similar_movies(params[:id])
  end

  private 
    def movie
        @movie = Tmdb::Movie.detail(params[:id])
        images = Tmdb::Movie.images(params[:id])
    end
end

#views/movies/show.html.erb
  <h3>Poster</h3>
  <%= image_tag("#{@configuration.base_url}w154#{movie[:poster_path]}") if movie[:poster_path] %>
  <h3>Test data</h3>
  Runtime: <%= movie[:runtime] %><br />
```

By making these changes, I can get the page to load with the correct ID, but none of the rails commands seem to run, so I just end up with a page that shows the html, but none of the pulled information is displayed.

Here is what shows in the terminal when I try to pull up a movie:

```
Started GET "/movies/329" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-19 14:32:07 -0700
Processing by MoviesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"329"}
  Rendered movies/show.html.erb within layouts/application (900.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2083ms (Views: 1011.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I think that I am just having some sort of syntax issue, but I honestly don't know. I think I also might be overthinking things. My SearchController and views are working properly, I just can't get the results with this controller/view though.

I really appreciate any help or advice to help me figure this out.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have an error message to share?

Comment: I don't actually have an error message. The page loads, but the view does not display the correct content. In the above, my Movies#Show view only displays the <h3> element, but the image_tag does not display. Same with the <% movie[:runtime] %> code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, when you had in the view the following line:

```
@movie.poster_path
```

you got the `NoMethodError` because `@movie` is a Hash returned by `Tmdb::Movie.detail(params[:id])`, and a `Hash` object doesn't have a `poster_path` method. The right way to access this is just `@movie[:poster_path]`, as you have almost written in your second attempt.

However, your second try doesn't work because `movie` is not the same as `@movie`. When you use the helper method you created in the view, `movie`, you aren't accessing the `@movie` Hash. As it's defined, it returns the result of the last line executed, that in your case is

```
images = Tmdb::Movie.images(params[:id])
```

So that's the value for `movie`, and since it doesn't have a `:poster_path` key, nothing is shown.

I believe you can make this works by removing your helper method and using `@movie["poster_path"]` in your view. I haven't used the `themoviedb` gem before, though, but I think that would be the way to go.

**Updated**

It looks like the hash returned by `Tmdb::Movie.detail(id)` has strings as keys rather than symbols, and it's not a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. Elements should be accessed using `@movie["poster_path"]` rather than `@movie[:poster_path]`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that enter sends a comment reply. I changed the view so that I am using      <%= image_tag("#{@configuration.base_url}w154#{@movie[:poster_path]}") if @movie[:poster_path] %>
      <h3>Test data</h3>
      Runtime: <%= @movie[:runtime] %><br /> .... but this is still not working when I try to view the detail movie page. The view just renders the html. This is a really detailed comment and I appreciate it. Glad to know that I was close in trying to fix it. I'm not sure what else is causing the issue.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also removed the helper method from the controller :)

Comment: I installed the gem and got an API key to have a try, and I believe I know what the problem is. The hash returned by the API doesn't use symbols as keys, but strings. There are kind of hash in Rails that handles this easily, [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), but using strings as keys should suffice for you. That is: `@movie["runtime"]` or `@movie["poster_path"]`

Comment: That was 100% correct! I really cannot thank you enough. I appreciate how much time and effort you put into helping me. Thank you!!!!!